# Page.ResolveClientUrl - can't resolve symbol

Tags: javascript, html

i added Page.ResolveClientUrl to my code and i get error in ids - can't resolve symbol  -  for example  i changed below link

```
<link id="cssId" 
href="/Resources/Shared/Plugin/Kendoui/styles/kendo.moonlight.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

to

```
<link id="cssId"
href="<%= Page.ResolveClientUrl("~/Resources/Shared/Plugin/Kendoui/styles/kendo.moonlight.css") %>" />
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try to use '~/Respirces/....'.
Use single quotes in double quotes

Answer (score 0):

For linking to stylesheet, simply use `~`, and ASP.NET will handle it for you:

```
<link id="cssId" rel="stylesheet"
  href="~/Resources/Shared/Plugin/Kendoui/styles/kendo.moonlight.css" />
```

Comment: no this not worked when i published my code on IIS application inside the site